# shmget significance of key_id

Tags: shared-memory

As far as I understand `errno 22` in case of shmget is becasue A shared memory segment is to be created and the value of size is less than the system-imposed minimum or greater than the system-imposed maximum.

But something which I dont understand is I am calling shmget in my server twice first time with key_id as IPC_PRIVATE and size as 64K and second time as key_id as some random number let say 200 and size as 64K and it always fails.

I tried reducing the size of second instance and behaviour which I am seeing is something which I am not able to understand

For `key_id > 250` the second instance allow only  till size 8k for key_id between 200 and 250 it allow me till 16K and for `key_id < 200` it allows me till 32000 bytes.

Also when I changes the order that is call the shmget with random key_id first and then with IPC private with size as 64K for both, it works fine.

Any pointers on why the key_id plays such an improtant role in first scenario. And why calling shmget with random key_id and then IPC_PRIVATE works but other way doesnt

I am using `Linux version 2.6.18-238.9.1.el5`(mockbuild@x86-002.build.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)) and language is C.